# ¿como genero objetos con un bucle en java?

Tags: java, poo, objeto

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Introduzca el numero deseado de objetos: ");
    int n = teclado.nextInt();
    String vector[] = new String[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre:");
        Familiares vector[i] = new Familiares("paco");
    }
}
```

encontre esto pero aun no me queda muy claro como genero a partir de una nueva instancia

Answer (score 1):

La segunda línea dentro del código parece incorrecta:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println( "Introduzca el numero deseado de objetos: " );
    int n = teclado.nextInt();
    String vector[] = new String[n];

    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        System.out.println( "Introduzca el nombre:" );
        //Familiares vector[i] = new Familiares("paco");
    }
}
```

Ya declaraste un array de objetos de tipo ***String*** con anterioridad, por tanto deberías ir añadiendo a éste, objetos de dicho tipo, y por como se ve el código además, leer los datos por teclado. Sustituiría tu bucle por éste otro:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
    System.out.println( "Introduzca el nombre:" );

    Scanner datoEntrada = new Scanner( System.in );
    vector[i] = (String) datoEntrada.nextLine(); //por ejemplo "Paco"
}
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Creo que quiere un vector de objetos `Familiares`, ¿ no?

Answer (score 0):

Primero te voy a explicar la línea en la que creas una instancia de la clase Familiares.

```
Familiares vector[i] = new Familiares("paco");
```

Lo que está haciendo esa línea de código es crear una instancia de la clase Familiares, en Familiares debe existir un constructor que me reciba un dato tipo string porque le estás enviando "paco", adicional al colocar esa línea dentro de un bucle vas a crear varias instancias llamadas de la misma forma y todas con el dato paco.

Ahora para almacenar datos en un array, primero debes crear el vector, leer el dato que necesita ingresar y almacenar el dato en el vector, sería así:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Introduzca el numero deseado de objetos: ");
    int n = teclado.nextInt();
    String nombre;
    String vector[] = new String[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre:");
        nombre = teclado.nextLine();
        vector[i] = nombre;
    }
}
```

Lo que está haciendo es crear y lee la variable n tipo int para definir el tamaño del array, luego crea la variable nombre tipo String para poder almacenar el nombre del dato que desea en cada posición del array, ingresa al ciclo y recorre el array, inicia en 0 y va hasta n, para cada posición va a leer el nombre y lo va a almacenar en la posición indicada del vector. Por ejemplo ingresé n=2, realizando prueba de escritorio quedaría algo así:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Introduzca el numero deseado de objetos: ");
    int n = teclado.nextInt(); // n=2

    String nombre;
    String vector[] = new String[2]; // asigna n = 2

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre:");
        nombre = teclado.nextLine(); // i = 0 , nombre =Marcela
        vector[i] = nombre; // vector[0] = Marcela
        //luego al subir al bucle va a aumentar i, sería algo así i = 0 + 1 por 
        //lo tanto i=1 y realiza nuevamente el proceso:
        //nombre = Camilo
        //vector[1] = Camilo;
        //i = 1 + 1 por lo tanto i=2 y al no cumplirse la condición del ciclo 
        // que i < 2, sale del ciclo y termina el programa.
    }
}
```

Espero haber sido clara con la información.
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un pequeño error de concepto.

Supongamos que esta es tu clase familiar y que va en otro fichero:

```
class Familiares {

    private String nombre;

    public Familiares(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    //ESTO ES PARA PODER VER MÁS FACILMENTE LA INFORMACIÓN QUE CONTIENE LA
    // INSTANCIA QUE CREAMOS. CADA INSTANCIA (new Familiar("paco")) TE 
    //   MOSTRARA SU INFO.
    @Override
    public String toString(){

        return "Nombre: "+this.nombre;

    }


}
```

Solo hay unos pequeños errores

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Introduzca el numero deseado de objetos: ");
    int n = teclado.nextInt();

    //ESTA LINEA TIENE QUE TENER DECLARADO EL TIPO FAMILIARES.
    // EL VECTOR ESTA CONFORMADO SOLO DE TIPOS FAMILIARES. 
    Familiares vector[] = new Familiares[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre:");
        String nombre = teclado.next();
        //NO ES NECESARIO VOLVER A DECLARAR Familiares Vector[] = .... 
        //POR QUE YA LA DECLARASTE Y LE DISTE SU TAMAÑO. 
        //LO QUE SE HACE AQUÍ ES CREAR LA INSTANCIA DE Famliares y guardarla
        // EN vector[i].

        vector[i] = new Familiares(nombre);

        // LA MANERA EN QUE LO TENIAS NO TE FUNCIONABA POR QUE INICIALIZABAS
        // CADA VEZ EL VECTOR PERO NO COMO String, SINO COMO Familiares. 
        // DICHO DE OTRA MANERA. BORRABAS LO ANTERIOR Y PONIAS ALGO NUEVO.

    }


    //ESTA LINEA SOLO ES PARA ITINERAR SOBRE TODOS LOS OBJETOS. 
    System.out.println("El modo que me gusta.");
    for (Familiares familiares : vector) {
        System.out.println(familiares.toString());
    }

    //TAMBIEN PUEDES HACERLO ASÍ, DIRECTAMENTE SOBRE EL VECTOR:
    System.out.println("El modo refinado");
    for (int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {
        Familiares familiares = vector[i];
        System.out.println(familiares.toString());
    }

    // O UN POCO MÁS INFORMAL. 
    System.out.println("El clásico");
    for (int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {

        System.out.println(vector[i].toString());
    }


}
```

De esta manera tienes cada objeto almacenado con su información. Lo bonito de esto es que puedes agregar más parámetros a la clase `Familiares` sin mucho temor a crear errores difíciles de seguir.

Comment: Muchas gracias angel acabo de ver despues de mucho tiempo voy empezando bueno llevo ya algo de tiempo en java se te agradece mucho espero tener contancto para quitarme de  mis dudas y empezar a desarrolar proyectos :)

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo usar ArrayList para guardar objetos:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

 Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("Introduzca el numero deseado de objetos: ");
 int n = teclado.nextInt();
 ArrayList<Familiares> familiaresAL = new ArrayList<>();

 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre:");
    Familiares familiar = new Familiares("paco");
    familiaresAL.add(familiar);     
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

package ejercicios;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lista {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Digite el tamaño del Vector: ");

    int num = input.nextInt();

    String nombre;
    String vector[] = new String[num];

    for (int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Id " + i + "\nDigite el nombre: ");
        nombre = input.next();
        vector[i] = nombre;
    }
    for (String datos : vector) {
        System.out.println(datos);

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Hola buenas lo que yo he hecho es con el for he definido el objeto dentro del bucle, i yo he puesto un 10 pero lo puedes adaptar a tu código

```
private static int i=0;
public static void main(String[] args) {

     Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduzca el numero deseado de objetos: ");
     
        String objeto="";
       
        for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
           
           objeto=teclado.next();
           
           System.out.println(objeto);             
       }            
}
```

Comment: llo tenia de antes por que lo probe con un while

Comment: pero me he molestado en ayudar no hace falta que respondas de esta manera

Comment: ya esta editado, espero que ahora te guste....